# Allow same-line empty methods in ReSharper

Tags: c#, resharper, resharper-9.0

Is there a way to tell ReSharper to allow same-line brackets for empty methods and constructors?

For example:

```
MyConstructor(int x) : BaseConstructor(x) { }

protected virtual void Foo() { }
```

Should **not** be converted to:

```
MyConstructor(int x) : BaseConstructor(x)
{
}

protected virtual void Foo()
{
}
```

In the first case, I don't need a method body, I simply supply the parent constructor with its arguments.

In the second case, I define an "optional abstract" method by making it virtual that therefore doesn't require a body.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to **ReSharper -> Options... -> Code Editing -> C# -> Formatting Style -> Braces Layout**.
Find **Empty braces formatting** and set it to **Together on the same line**.

Here's a screenshot that shows you how to find the setting.

[image]

Comment: For some reason, I managed to spend an hour in the settings and still missed it. Thanks a bunch!